# Extract file name with directory structure for internal web site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, express

**Environment:**

html5

JavaScript

Angularjs

node.js

express.js

Couchbase

**Question**:

I understand the concerns and security measures implemented within the web environment to prevent the display of directory paths to the world.  However, I have an issue that requires knowing the full directory path to a selected file.

I am building a web page for an internal website.  The web page needs to allow the user to select a tab delimited file.  This tab delimited file will exist on a network server, which is a policy instituted by the company and mandated by external auditors.  This file may exist for various clients, with data specific to the client.  With that said, the files will reside within different folder structures on the server(s).  The user wants to pick the appropriate file and have the data uploaded to the database.  Based on the size of the file (up to 10’s of millions of rows), the user does not want to wait for the web page to process immediately.  Therefore, the solution is to create a task.  The task will contain all the parameters necessary to manipulate the data prior to uploading the data to the database.  I understand the simple solution is to upload the file to a common directory but that is not practical.  As the user could set up several tasks that will upload the same tab delimited file to the database using different parameters.

I would like to have my task creation process contain the file name with the directory structure.  When the background process executes the task, it can extract the data from the original location.  Additionally, if I have multiple tasks extracting the same data, I not concerned I may have multiple copies of the data present.

I will appreciate any help with code snippets, website, etc. that may suggest methods to resolving this issue.  Please not, that at the current moment, PHP is not an option.  A management decision prevents the use of PHP.

TIA

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly possible, so I see two solutions. One is to try and get the path to the temporary location of the file, rather than the actual permanent location.

Suppose your  has an id of fileInput and you're using jQuery:

```
$('#fileInput').change( function(event) {
    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

 console.log("Temporary Path(Copy it and try pasting it in browser address bar):"
 console.log(tmppath);
});
```

Otherwise I would just make a separate input for path, and show a brief instruction to users on how to copy-paste the URL from their Windows Explorer window.